# Bootstrap responsive design Divs overlap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am a newbie to responsive elements in bootstrap. These two divs whose HTML is given below, in mywebapp ( Ex: http://greenboard.in/noticeDescription.html?noticeId=60 ) overlap with each other in mobile screens. Resize the browser's window to see the behavior. How should I overcome that behavior?

```
 <!-- DIV1 -->
 <div class = "col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <a href= "/" id="logo-dark"> <img class="img-responsive" width="60" height="60" alt="" src="images/logo-dark-sm.png"> </a>
 </div>

<!-- DIV2 -->

 <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" style="margin-top: 25px;">
     <div id="DescriptionWrapper"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you want the second div to appear to the right of the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The css of your logo is:

```
#logo-dark, #logo-light {
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
```

This means your logo is going to stay in the top-left position regardless of the elements around it, that's why your next element is overlapping with the logo.

There are two ways you can solve this:

1) Replace the `position:absolute;` with `position:relative;` for smaller viewports using media queries.

2)

*a)* Add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` in between the divs

*b)* Leave more  margin space at the second div `margin-top: 35px;`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple bootstrap. On this case divs never overlap

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">


      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">


      </div>
  </div>
```